# Excel VBA loop through cells in a column looking for integer

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new with VBA, but I have a good understanding on how for loop and if-else statement works.  I have created a worksheet that needs to loop through the entire column of "C" looking for any integer.  If found, I would like to add a letter "s" at the end of the current cell value. I have the following, but I am guessing my syntax is incorrect.   Any pointer will be appreciated.

```
Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
j = 2
For i = 2 To N
If IsNumeric(Sheet7.Range("C") & i) = True Then
Sheet7.Range("C" & i) = Sheet7.Range("C" & i) & "s"
Next i
End If
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use SpecialCells for this and get a range object of all cells holding numeric values. Instead of iterating all cells.

Comment: Just a few typos towards the end and you need to assess the `.Value` property of the cell / range: `If IsNumeric(Sheet7.Range("C" & i).Value) Then
Sheet7.Range("C" & i).Value = Sheet7.Range("C" & i).Value & "s"
Next i` should be alright (only a quick glance hence just a comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cells indexing like this:

```
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long 
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
    For i = 2 To N
        if isNumeric(Cells(i,3)) then
            Cells(i,3) = cells(i,3) & "S"
        end if
    Next
```

Where "i" is the row iterating in the loop, and 3 is the "C" column.Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your input, it was very helpful. @ jsanchezs, awesome suggestion, your code works flawlessly.  Happy coding!!